# HTML table as background?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I used an html table to make some cellular automata animations and would like to have those animations as the background of a webpage. Is it possible to make a table the background of the page?

Comment: add some code what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible. What you'd want to do is fill the page with the table, by setting its position to absolute, forcing it into the top left corner, and width/height values to 100%:

```
#your-table {
    position: absolute;

    /* Force table into the top right corner */
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

    /* Expand table out into the rest of the window */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you set [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to "none," most browsers will prevent the cursor from changing when the user mouses over the content. There is also [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select), that can be used to [disable text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting). Thus I suggest adding the following CSS rules to your background table to make it behave more like a background:

```
/* Disable pointer events */
pointer-events: none;

/* Disable text selection highlighting */
-webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
 -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
   -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
        user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              supported by Chrome, Opera and Firefox */
```

Best of luck on your project!

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!

Comment: No problem @guru-har-narayan-khalsa! If this solution worked for you I'd appreciate it if you'd accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While you can certainly stack elements over your table, you can not use a table in the same way as you would a background image. It would be helpful if you provided an example of what you have now and what you are trying to achieve.